# Modify destination application name and instance for an AWS MediaLive RTMP(push) input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-live

How can I modify through AWS CLI or AWS SDK the Destination A or Destination B application name and instance name for a MediaLive RTMP(push) input?

According to the [update-input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/medialive/update-input.html), there is a way to update Destinations, but so far it looks like only StreamName is exposed to be changed.

These two props can be changed in the UI(see the below image) and I assume there is a way to do it with CLI.

[image: AWS MediaLive change input's application name and instance]

Answer (score 0):

Use `/` to separate application name from application instance in the update request for the `--destinations` parameter.

```
[
  {
    "StreamName": "name/instance"
  }
  ...
]
```